# Cannot connect to connect to http://127.0.0.1:5984/

Tags: connection, couchdb

I am new to CouchDB and I've just successfully installed it on my Windows 10 machine.

After the installation, when I try to connect to http://127.0.0.1:5984/ I am getting

> 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

Is there anything additional I should do?

Comment: Have you opened port 5984?

Comment: You may have installed CouchDB, but did you start it?